# Is there a way to change the print dialog in Google sheets to either default to last selection OR to "selected cells"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons

I almost never want to print an entire worksheet.  I usually want to print a block 15 rows by 8 columns.

Every #*$&^$* time I have to change from "print entire sheet" to "print selected cells"  Is there a way to make this change permanent, so that the DEFAULT is to print selected cells.

Curiously the print dialog remembers centering from the previous print.

(To fore-stall comments:  Yes, I have mentioned this in sheets feedback.  Several times.)